# Comparion between java 8 parallel stream and spring batch

Tags: spring, java-8, spring-batch, spring-scheduled

I have one queue where messages will be put by some other application and what my application does is just poll the queue and take all the messages and convert into other object and persist in database.
So, I have two approaches for this
1.) Using spring scheduler and poll every 5 seconds for all messages and then use parallel stream of java 8 to persist in database as all stream is independent.
2.) Some one suggested to use spring batch, but hard luck ,I have not got sufficient explanation for using spring batch.

Can you please throw some suggestions with explanation to help me out, like which one can be useful and better?

Comment: how is the title connected to the actual thing that you are describing in the question?

Comment: Well it is connected, comparison between either spring batch parallel processing or using schedular and java 8 parallel stream.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have understanding of option 1. For option-2 using spring batch find explanation below.

Because you are using spring, you can use spring batch solution. as all your steps will be clearly maintained and you can use parallellism and page size. scale your performance .

1. reader : read your queue
2. processor : process your data
3. writer: write to your database  here you can mention your batch size.

You can have multiple steps , or reading from multiple sources (though you just have one queue to read from) , multiple processors , and writers and listeners for each of these operations. e.g. you can have listeners to listen from your queue to read from.
And there are a lot of configuration you will find useful as given in this [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/)

And of course there is a very good documentation and support for spring batch.

But even though i myself is a big fan of spring , if yours is very simple read and write application, you dont want to use another framework, you may not use spring batch.

Comment: Seems for simple read and write operation spring batch framework may not be suitable.

Comment: Correct , for simple read write operations you may not want to over engineer. For a rule based processing, multi step operation and complex batch processing,spring batch is really easy and gives a good maintain ability.

Answer (score 0):

For simple operations no need to use spring batch .